# ¿Porqué da error al establecer un PageAdapter a mi ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alertdialog, android-viewpager

Quiero mostrar un ViewPager con varios fragments en un Dialog. Estoy trabajando con un AlertDialog, este es el layout de mi diálogo (preview_styles):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Luego tengo el del fragmento que utilizo en el viewpager (fragment_style)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dramos.myapplication.StyleFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/fwebView"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/fragment_info"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Por defecto"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Este es mi adaptador del ViewPager:

```
public class SlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        /*
         * IMPORTANT: This is the point. We create a RootFragment acting as
         * a container for other fragments
         */
         return new StyleFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Este es el código empleado para lanzar el dialog en MainActivity

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preview_styles, null);
mPager = (ViewPager) layout.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
mPagerAdapter = new SlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
mPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
dialog.setView(layout).setPositiveButton("Aceptar",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).create();
dialog.show();
```

Y este es el error que me lanza:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d009f (com.example.dramos.myapplication:id/view_pager) for fragment StyleFragment{43675048 #0 id=0x7f0d009f android:switcher:2131558559:0}

Answer (score 0):

Si estas abriendo el dialog desde tu fragment cambia:

```
mPagerAdapter = new SlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

por

```
mPagerAdapter = new SlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

**Adicionalmente** estas obteniendo la instancia de tu viewPager desde el layout del fragment

```
mPager = (ViewPager) layout.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
```

deberia ser asi:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
```

Comment: Lo estoy abriendo desde mi MainActivity.

Comment: actualize la respuesta con una nueva observacion